# Using Shared Preferences to save if an item has been clicked in a Recycler View

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I am trying to make a list of songs and I want to add an indicator if a song has already been opened by the user. So I want to save a boolean in Shared Preferences if it's been clicked or not. But I can not getSharedPreference in the recycler's adapter or neither can I use it in MainActivity since I can't use a variable if it's local. Can anyone help? Here's MainActivity and RecyclerAdapter:

```
package com.example.praqtikuli

import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.Image
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var myFunc: (Song) -> Unit = { mySong ->
        val myInt = Intent(this, MainActivity2::class.java)
        myInt.putExtra("lyrics", mySong.lyrics)
        myInt.putExtra("name", mySong.name)
        myInt.putExtra("artist", mySong.artist)

        startActivity(myInt)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val myPref = getSharedPreferences("My_Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
        val statusBool = myPref.getBoolean("isOpened", false)

        val songs = listOf(
            Song("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/ad/Joji_-_Run.png", "Run", "Joji", "Color: Black", statusBool),
            Song("https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b27367d0cba50eae9026b8958755", "As The World Caves In", "Matt Maltese", "Color: Red", false),
            Song("https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-000218815937-39y82q-t500x500.jpg", "CtrlAltDelete", "Bones", "Color: White", false),
            Song("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/d/d1/Revenge_XXXTENTACION_MIXTAPE.png", "Revenge", "XXXTentacion", "hmm", false),
            Song("https://cdns-images.dzcdn.net/images/cover/e31287495f374bc12d135a7ea344d2c5/500x500.jpg", "Bank Account", "21 Savage", "hmmgh", false),
            Song("https://i1.sndcdn.com/artworks-CMp3BhyA2CR5oBKe-SKzacw-t500x500.jpg", "Like You Do", "Joji", "lol", false),
            Song("https://i.scdn.co/image/ab67616d0000b2730d5a84e4e47399d2726c330c", "XO TOUR Lif3", "Lil Uzi Vert", "loll", false)
        )

        val myRecycler = findViewById<RecyclerView>(R.id.vanikosRecycler)
        myRecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
        myRecycler.adapter = RecyclerAdapter(songs, myFunc)
    }
}
```

Here's the adapter:

```
package com.example.praqtikuli
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso

class RecyclerAdapter(val Songs: List<Song>, val myFunc: (Song) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyHolder>() {
    inner class MyHolder(view: View): RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
        var vhSong: Song? = null

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener{
                myFunc(vhSong!!)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyHolder {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false)
        return MyHolder(v)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
        val song = Songs[position]
        holder.vhSong = song

        val songCover = holder.itemView.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.coverImage)
        Picasso.get().load(song.cover).into(songCover)

        val songName = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.nameText)
        songName.text = song.name

        val carYear = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.artistText)
        carYear.text = song.artist

        val songStatus = holder.itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.statusText)
        songStatus.text = song.opened.toString()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return Songs.size
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just add needed `Context` as a param for adapter. `class RecyclerAdapter(val Context ctx, ...` and pass `this` as first argument (`RecyclerAdapter(this, songs, myFunc)`, as `this` refers to this class , which is an `Activity`, which `extends Context`

you can (should) store `SharedPrefences` instance inside adapter at the beginning, in constructor, then `Context` doesn't need to be `val` as it won't be used further, only for constructor for obtaining SP instance. read from it in every `onCreateViewHolder` call instead of calling all relevant methods in runtime (like `getSharedPreferences()`)

edit: some lines

exchange this constructor

```
class RecyclerAdapter(val Songs: List<Song>, val myFunc: (Song) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyHolder>() {
```

to this

```
class RecyclerAdapter(val Context: ctx, val Songs: List<Song>, val myFunc: (Song) -> Unit): RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.MyHolder>() {
```

exchange this line of adapter creation

```
RecyclerAdapter(songs, myFunc)
```

to below, add introduced `Context` param

```
RecyclerAdapter(this@MainActivity, songs, myFunc)
```

(or just `this`, as in Java)

now you can call `ctx.getSharedPreferences("My_Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean(...` or `ctx.getSharedPreferences("My_Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(...` in any method for checking if such URL was opened

btw. use key which can identify every item, single `isOpened` won't be sufficient. you may use e.g. `"isOpened" + song.name + song.artist` as key (which be unique for this song only)

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyHolder, position: Int) {
    val song = Songs[position]
    val opened = ctx.getSharedPreferences("My_Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).
        getBoolean("isOpened" + song.name + song.artist, false)
    //rest of code, adjust GUI
```

store clicks in your click function

```
    itemView.setOnClickListener{
        ctx.getSharedPreferences("My_Pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
            putBoolean("isOpened" + vhSong!!.name + vhSong!!.artist, true).apply()
        myFunc(vhSong!!)
    }
```

I don't have IDE currently, so in my snippets there may be some minor bugs or mispells, as nothing will red-underline these for me and prevent building ;)

Comment: Hello. Thanks a lot for the answer. I apologize first, cause I'm a beginner at this and I didn't fully understand your answer, although I do believe it can be the solution. Can you please go in a little more detail on this? Maybe guide me through the steps on what I need to edit. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: added more explanation, now it looks like copy-pasteable tutorial